# AWS cannot "create new DeviceFarm project" for code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-device-farm

I am following the instruction to create an Android based devicefarm test pipeline.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-codebuild-devicefarm.html

However, it seems AWS changed the console a lot and there is no way to create a new devicefarm project on the fly (in the configuration of pipeline). Then I switched to create a devicefarm project out of the pipeline but I still cannot find a way to connect the pipeline with the devicefarm. I even couldn't find a devicefarm project ID (only "arn"!). Besides, the "AppType" and "TestType" are just text inputs rather than multiple choice menu.

Here is a snapshot when I tried to add devicefarm in the code pipeline:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from AWS service team:

You are correct in your understanding that a DeviceFarm Project cannot be created during the Pipeline Stage creation. The Device Farm Project needs to be created from the DeviceFarm Console and be referred in the Pipeline.

However, I confirmed that the DeviceFarm Project creation does not require a .apk file. I replicated and verified the scenario in my Account by creating a Device Farm Project and a Device Pool and created a Pipeline for a .apk evaluation.

In my replication, I created a CodeCommit Repository and added a ready-made .apk file in that. You can choose to keep your code in CodeCommit/Git and have CodeBuild compile the package for you into a .apk file as mentioned in the guide you shared. [1]

So, here are the steps that I followed for the setup:

1. Go to DeviceFarm Console and create a Project [2]. In the documentation [2], you may choose to skip Step4 and choose to configure the Project later.
2. Once the Project is created, navigate inside the Project and select 'Project settings'.
3. Navigate to the 'Device Pools' tab.
4. Please create a new device pool and select the devices [3], you would want to run the test on. In my replication, I used a Pixel 3 with Android 9.
5. For using the DeviceFarm Project and the Device Pool in the Pipeline, you would need details regarding the implementation, such as the Project ID and the Device Pool ARN. To fetch these details, please configure AWS CLI for us-west-2 [4], since Device Farm is only available in Oregon.
6. Once you have configured AWS CLI to run in us-west-2, please run the command [5]:

   aws devicefarm list-projects

This should return a list of the Projects available. Please locate the desired Project using the name of the Project and note down the ARN.

In this example ARN:   arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:123456789101:project:5e01a8c7-c861-4c0a-b1d5-12345EXAMPLE
This is the Project ID:   5e01a8c7-c861-4c0a-b1d5-12345EXAMPLE

We would require the Project ID while setting up the Pipeline.

7. Once you have the Project ARN, please run the command [6]:

   aws devicefarm list-device-pools --arn arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:123456789101:project:5e01a8c7-c861-4c0a-b1d5-12345EXAMPLE

This would give you the list of the device pools. Please identify the Device Pool from the list and note down the ARN of it. 
Example:  arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:123456789101:devicepool:1ab2c7c3-741e-4df8-af6d-85d3ca1d1234/06d26e98-3b87-1234-9cb3-1234abcde

8. Please navigate to the CodePipeline Console and create a Pipeline. For the Source stage, I selected the CodeCommit Repository and Branch where I have my .apk file.
9. I skipped the Build stage and in the Deploy stage, I selected S3 as the deploy provider.
10. Once the Pipeline is created, please edit the Pipeline and delete the S3 Deploy Action.
11. You can add an Action group / Action; and in the Action Provider Select 'AWS Device Farm'.
12. Please keep the Region same as the Pipeline.
13. In Input Artifact, select 'Source Artifact'. If CodeBuild is generating the .apk file, then it should be 'Build Artifact'. This depends on the Artifact name settings you have in the pipeline.
14. Now, please enter the Project ID for the Device Farm Project that we kept aside earlier: 5e01a8c7-c861-4c0a-b1d5-12345EXAMPLE
15. In 'DevicePoolArn', please enter the ARN of the Device Pool that we fetched in Step 7.
16. In 'AppType', since I'm testing this on a Pixel device, I used the value 'Android'. You may choose to use 'iOS' in case the application is intended for Apple devices.
17. In the field 'App - optional', I used the name of the .apk file, which in my case is 'SimpleCalculator.apk'. If you are using CodeBuild you can set the name of the APK file in the [artifacts -> files] section of the Buildspec file.
18. For the 'TestType', I used the value 'BUILTIN_FUZZ' .

For a list of valid values, you can check out the 'type' section of this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_Suite.html

19. Save the Action and the Pipeline configuration and you're done! :)

Your pipeline will provide/create the APKs and Device Farm will dynamically ingest them and produce reports based on them. You can optionally configure your Device Farm Project with more granular settings and/or you can configure your Deploy Action as per your requirement.

References:

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-codebuild-devicefarm.html#codepipeline-configure-tests

[2] Create a Project in AWS Device Farm - Create a Project (Console) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-project.html#how-to-create-project-console

[3] Create a Device Pool in AWS Device Farm - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-device-pool.html

[4] Configuring the AWS CLI - Quickly Configuring the AWS CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration

[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-projects.html

[6] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-device-pools.html